# Should I use java.io or java.nio for my network client implementation?

Tags: java, io, client, nio

So I'm creating a game, very basic multiplayer. I've got the server side down using asynchronous non-blocking I/O (raw `java.nio`) but now I need to design the client.

I'm not sure how I should do this. My gut tells me using NIO for a client is overkill (it's not like it's going to handle multiple connections, right?) but I want a second opinion.

So the question is, for a *single-connection* client, is the best option to use `java.io`, or `java.nio`?

And, if the best option is standard I/O, is it still good practice to use `ByteBuffer`s? Or just the usual byte arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance may vary, but it is platform dependant and most likely insignificant. For example, tests I've done have shown that NIO and standard I/O perform differently on Linux and Windows. When sending large amounts of data, NIO performed better on the Linux platform, but it was the opposite on Windows. Note: I had configured sockets to be blocking on NIO. When writing a client application, there is little reason to be using non-blocking I/O and polling.

I would not worry about performance. It is hard to say which is better in that sense. Go with what you are comfortable with. If you want to use standard I/O, but still would like to use ByteBuffers, what you can do is wrap the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` of the Socket using [newChannel(InputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [newChannel(OutputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel%28java.io.OutputStream%29), respectively. However, there is overhead from additional synchronization and other checks. My advice is to use `java.nio` and use blocking I/O (`configureBlocking(true)`).

Comment: What about what I posted in the previous comment: just using `ByteBuffer.array()` to write and then something like `InputStream.read(ByteBuffer.array()` to read?

Comment: @David: Yes, that's a viable option as well. It's probably better than using the `newChannel` methods, actually, because there is no extra overhead from synchronization and other checks. I also forgot that the I/O operations would be non-blocking if you used `newChannel`. I'll make the appropriate edits to my post :).

Comment: @David Correction: the I/O in a channel derived from Channels.newChannel() will be *blocking.*

Comment: @EJP: You're right, sorry. Its seems I misread the code last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Stream I/O is a lot easier to handle, and not necessarily slower. It internally uses NIO, for the network accesses, too, I think. (Of course, if you can simply reuse your server's code, using it might be an option.)

As OutputStream does not support writing a ByteBuffer, there is no point in using it here.

(Disclaimer: This is just my opinion (and experience from trying to port my stream IO based networking package to NIO). I'm not sure about *best practice* here.)

Comment: It would be pretty easy to re-use my server code, and that would probably also make it easier to encode/decode my data as well (copy and paste new methods much? :P) 

When I meant using a byte buffer, I said it because it has the extra methods that a normal byte array would not. `OutputStream` does of course support `write(byte[])` and `ByteBuffer` has a `byte[](array())` method. So would it be worth it?

Comment: Data(In|Out)putStream might be worth a look, if you simply need the encode/decode methods. Avoid Copy+Paste, if possible.

Comment: On the other hand, having a second (independent) implementation of your protocol could help make you sure that you got it right. This means you should first write down the protocol, though.

Comment: Note that if you use Data(In|Out)putStream, make sure to wrap the socket (In|Out)putStream under a Buffered(In|Out)Stream, or else I/O could be rather expensive.

Comment: The only methods that I would use in those Data Stream classes would be readUnsigned(Short|Byte), I'm not sure if it's worth the extra casts/initializations though.